# Running automation tests on 2 TeamCity agents in parallel

Tags: teamcity

We use TeamCity with MsTest to manage and run an automation test suite for front-end testing of a WPF application.

Currently the test suite is running on one dedicated test agent (where TC is installed) and I'm now at a stage where I need to dramatically reduce the overall time it takes to run. I want to do this by adding another test agent to run the tests in parallel.

My test scenarios are large so I have them separated into approx 4 Specflow feature files that run in sequence. All these test scenarios are also categorised by their functional areas.

**Firstly:**
Is it possible to configure TeamCity to have one test agent managing the sending of tests to be run on each test agent? And then collating all results at the end!

**Secondly:**
And also keeping the categorised tests together that need to run in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use 2 separate project configurations in my TC setup. Each project is pointing at a different test agent using the Agent Requirements step. And I have simply divided up the test categories (that I have setup in my test scenarios anyhow) for each project (half and half).

**Pro:**
Simple solution and easy to maintain

**Con:**
Results for each build are separated in TC